# Running the same program sometimes results in Decode error - output not utf8 and sometimes not

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

I am programming in Python 2 and have a program which uses chinese characters. I set the sys default encoding to 'utf-8', and it works most of the time. When I run the program multiple times, it sometimes gives

> [Decode error - output not utf-8]

and sometimes works perfectly and prints the correct chinese output. I am running the exact same code (using Sublime Text). Any ideas why this might be? I'm confused why running the exact same code sometimes gives the desired Chinese output and sometimes gives an encoding error. I'm not sure how to give a minimal example, as this error happens only sometimes when I run the code.

Comment: what is input to your program?

Comment: It is supposed to print the chinese characters: 我要吃饭. It mostly prints this, but sometimes upon running it it gives a decode error. Is this a Sublime problem, rather than a Python problem?

Comment: Input is just an english string: as a translation program, the string as input which would give the output above would be "I want to eat rice."

Comment: I am literally just pressing ctrl+B (build, in SublimeText) over and over and seeing different results come out. Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure the same code executes every time? You're not doing anything like `if random.choice([True, False]):` or `#execute this code only when the minute is even`, right?

Comment: This happens when you `print`, right? Do you print one character at a time, or all the characters at once, or something else? Does it crash at the first `print`, or some other time?

Comment: Nope, no randomness at all. I am using the print command, yes. I print the string (a variable which contains the string of chinese characters). It crashes at some other time; the first print seems to work fine.